# Can a qunit Tests case be written in ecplise?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, qunit, js-test-driver

Recently i have given a task of Qunit with Eclipse plugin.I could find the information regarding the tests cases written in Qunit and the conversion and building the solution for it in JS-test runner using Quint-Adaptaer. But My Question is do i have any Environment in ecplise where i can write tests cases in Qunit and run with JS-Test Runner?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking about a development tools for JavaScript.  I would recommend installing VJet.  This provides tools like a JS editor, content assist, navigation, hovers, validation, etc.

See the page here for more information:

http://www.eclipse.org/vjet/

Here is the update site to use to install:

http://download.eclipse.org/vjet/updates-0.9

Answer (score 0):

If you need advanced content assist for QUnit (or other JavaScript frameworks like Angular, dojo, jQuery, node, etc), I suggest you that you [install tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) 0.10.0-SNAPSHOT (not released today). The 0.10.0 tern.java version provides a [support for QUnit](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-QUnit-support):

[image: QUnit completion]